# 32 bit Datapath RISCV core

Tags: riscv

I'm trying to parametrize the rocket core by changing the configuration in PublicConfig.scala.

However, when I change XprLen and L1D_SETS to 32, I have a compilation problem.

What is the proper way to genarate a 32 bit data path with the Rocket Chip Generator, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rocket-chip does not currently support generating a 32b processor.

While the required changes to the datapath would be minimal, the host-target interface for communicating to the front-end server (as Rocket currently only runs in a tethered mode) has only been spec'ed out for 64b cores.

ALso, `L1D_SETS` is the number of "sets" in the L1 data-cache (such that `L1D_WAYS` * `L1D_SETS` * 64 bytes per line is the total cache capacity in bytes).